# cron job with laravel to send emails to user

Tags: laravel, cron

please help me i'm trying to make a cron job on my server to send email to user
i created a command like that :

```
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'contract:end';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send an email to user about the end of a contract';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $contracts = Contract::where('end_date', Carbon::parse(today())->toDateString())->get();

        foreach ($contracts as $contract) {
            Mail::to(Setting::first()->value('email'))->send(new ContractEmail($contract));
        }
    }
```

and in my `kernel.php` i added the following code :

```
  * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
        Commands\ContractEnd::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('contract:end')
                  ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
```

and on my server i run the following command to run the cron job :

```
cd /archive/artisan && schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but it didn't send any email , can anyone help me as it's my first time using it ?

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue by seeing if the email sends from manually running it? `php artisan contract:end`. If not, we will no the cron is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Because your command in your server is wrong you need to specify the correct path which will contain/home/your username/your website folder/artisan like this
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/your user name which you can get in from job page/archive/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: first thank you for your comment but i already looked in some tutorials and they specified it like i wrote above there !
and when i use the command you say about it , the cron job couldn't even be created